# Foreign keys vs secondary keys

Tags: sql

I used to think that foreign key and secondary key are the same thing.

After Googling the result are even more confusing, some consider them to be the same, others said that a secondary key is an index that doesn't have to be unique, and allows faster access to data than with the primary key.

Can someone explain the difference?
Or is it indeed a case of mixed terminology?
Does it maybe differ per database type?

Comment: https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SoftDevRDS02CD/page_03.htm: all sorts of keys

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The definition in [wiki/Foreign_key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) states that:

> In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or
>   collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of
>   another table. In other words, a foreign key is a column or a
>   combination of columns that is used to establish and enforce a link
>   between two tables.
>
> The table containing the foreign key is called the referencing or
>   child table, and the table containing the candidate key is called the
>   referenced or parent table.

Take the example of the case:

A customer may place 0,1 or more orders.

From the point of the business, each customer is identified by a unique id (Primary Key) and instead of repeating the customer information with each order, we place a reference, or a pointer to that unique customer id (Customer's Primary Key) in the order table. By looking at any order, we can tell who placed it using the unique customer id.

The relationship established between the parent (Customer table) and the child table (Order table) is established when you set the value of the FK in the Order table after the Customer row has been inserted. Also, deleting a child row may affect the parent depending on your Referential Integrity stings (Cascading Rules) established when the FK was created. FKs help establish integrity in a relational database system.

As for the "Secondary Key", the term refers to a structure of 1 or more columns that together help retrieve 1 or more rows of the same table. The word 'key' is somewhat misleading to some. The Secondary Key does not have to be unique (unlike the PK). It is not the Primary Key of the table. It is used to locate rows in the same table it is defined within (unlike the FK). Its enforcement is only through an index (either unique or not) and it is implementation is optional. A table could have 0,1 or more Secondary Key(s). For example, in  an Employee table, you may use an auto generated column as a  primary key. Alternatively, you may decide to use the Employee Number or SSN to retrieve employee(s) information.

Sometimes people mix the term "Secondary Key" with the term "Candidate Key" or "Alternate Key" (usually appears in Normalization context) but they are all different.

Comment: there is an answer telling that the secondary might be the candidate, thx for correcting that, but i still can understand what's the difference between normal rows and the secondary key

Comment: I mean, why would i create a secondary key, what's is interest, as you can also retrieve the employee informations using the field address for example, or by name, and this last could return  more than one row just like the secondary

Comment: You create a Secondary Key to help you find rows in a different way that is probably more suitable to your business case other than by using the PK. An employee for example, may not remember his/her SSN but can remember his/her Family Name. As of the other definition considering a secondary key a candidate key, I disagree since the secondary key does not have to be unique whereas a Candidate key is unique.

Answer (score 4):

A foreign key is a key that references an index on some other table. For example, if you have a table of customers, one of the columns on that table may be a country column which would just contain an ID number, which would match the ID of that country in a separate Country table. That country column in the customer table would be a foreign key.

A secondary key on the other hand is just a different column in the table that you have used to create an index (which is used to speed up queries). Foreign keys have nothing to do with improving query speeds.

Answer (score 3):

"Secondary key" is not a term I'm familiar with. It doesn't appear in the index of [Database Design for Mere Mortals](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Database-Design-for-Mere-Mortals-Michael-J-Hernandez/9780321884497) and I don't remember it in [Pro SQL Server 2012 Relational Database Design and Implementation](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Pro-SQL-Server-2012-Relational-Database-Design-Implementation-Louis-Davidson/9781430236955) (my two "goto" books for database design). It also doesn't appear in the index for [SQL for Smarties](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Joe-Celkos-SQL-for-Smarties-Joe-Celko/9780123820228). It sounds like its not an actual term at all.

I've always used the term "candidate key".

A candidate key is a way to uniquely identify an entity. You identify all the candidate keys during the design phase of a database system. During the implementation phase, you will decide on a primary key: either one of the candidate keys or an artificial key. The primary key will probably be implemented with a primary key constraint; the candidate keys will probably be implemented with unique constraints.

A foreign key is an instance of one entity's candidate key in another entity, representing a relationship between the two entities. It will probably be implemented with a foreign key constraints.