# Secondary key vs secondary attribute in databases

Tags: database

I looked for this all over the internet but found nothing. I know what secondary key are, but I do not know if there is a difference between secondary key and secondary attribute? What is a secondary attribute?
Note that I study this on my mother language and not in English, "secondary attribute" might just be a mistranslation. 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't heard the term 'secondary key' so I looked it up and [found it is not a widely used term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668291/foreign-keys-vs-secondary-keys). Apparently the 'key' part in 'secondary key' is not actually  a true database key! Rather it is when an attribute added to a true key when creating an index.

Needless to say, I'd never heard of 'secondary attribute' either but I would guess it is the aforementioned attribute added to a true key to make a 'secondary key'.

Comment: Thank you for help. Well as you might have guessed it, your not knowing about these is not your fault - at the university I study at english is not our teachers' strong suit, those must have been a mistranslation, or a mirror translation without looking things up, 
I think by `secondary attribute` they meant `non-prime attribute`. 
You made things clear, though i might ask them politely not to try english again :D