# difference between secondary key, foreign key, and primary key?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I tried searching google to find this but I can't find a comparison between them. If anyone can tell me will be a great help.

Comment: http://cstechpause.blogspot.com/2014/10/difference-between-primary-key.html  This can be a good start for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign keys vs secondary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668291/foreign-keys-vs-secondary-keys)

Comment: Or https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SoftDevRDS02CD/page_03.htm for another start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Primary Key**

- The attribute that uniquely identifies a row or record in a relation is known as primary key
  -like page number of a book

**Secondary Key**

- A field or combination of fields that is basis for retrieval is known as secondary key (mainly used for finding details from large data)
- like an index page of a book

**Foreign Key**

- A field used to refer records in another table(primary key of refered table )

Answer (score 0):

**Primary Key:** Is a **single** field chosen by the designer to uniquely identify a record in a table (relation), cannot be null (empty/unassigned).

**Foreign Key:** Is the Primary Key one table appearing (cross-referenced) in **another table**.

**Secondary (or Alternative) Key:** Is any field in the table that isn't selected to be any of the two types above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A primary key isn't necessarily just one column. And for the secondary key, it's not any column not chosen to be a primary key, it also must be a key. A column or a combination of columns is a key when no two tuples can exist, that are equal regarding the key columns. (From the logical point of view, not only according to the current data.)

Comment: ... and a foreign key is not required to reference a key that is primary, but can instead reference any declared key.  Which gives us three serious errors in three small bullets :-(  I wonder who those upvoters are.

Answer (score 0):

It is traditional in SQL to designate one of the keys of a table as the "primary key". A "secondary" or "alternate" key is any key that is not selected as the primary. (The distinction doesn't have any basis in relational theory.)

A foreign key is a rather different kind of thing, and should have its own question.